# exact vector tracing of square pixels

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to find or implement an image processing function in Python to vector trace black and white bitmap images. The function should take a 2 dimensional NumPy array of zeros and ones as a representation of the image and return a list of vector polygons. The zeros in the array should represent the white pixels in the image and the ones in the array should represent the black pixels in the image. The pixels should be interpreted as unit squares (all sides of length 1) and the returned polygons should trace the exact boundaries between the black and white pixels. The polygons should consist only of horizontal and vertical line segments. That is, all of their corners should have an angle of exactly 90 degrees. Each of the returned polygons should be given as a list of the coordinates of its corners with each coordinate given as a (x, y) tuple pair of integers. The polygons can contain repeated coordinate points, but not self intersect. That is, the line segments of the polygons can touch at a point but not cross each other. The polygon that traces the outermost boundary of the black pixels should have its coordinates listed in clockwise order. Any polygon that traces a 'hole' in the group of black pixels should have its coordinates listed in counterclockwise order. The coordinates for each polygon should start with the point at the lower left.

Some examples:

[image]

There is a single black pixel. The function should return [[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]]. The polygon is shown in red.

[image]

There are eight black pixels around a single white pixel hole. The function should return [[(0, 0), (0, 3), (3, 3), (3, 0)], [(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)]]. The first polygon is the trace around the outer border. It is shown in red and its coordinates are listed clockwise. The second polygon is the trace around the hole. It is shown in green and its coordinates are listed counter-clockwise.

[image]

There are thirteen black pixels around a pair of holes. The function should return [[(0, 0), (0, 5), (3, 5), (3, 0)], [(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)], [(1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (1, 4)]]. The first polygon is the trace around the outer border. It is shown in red and its coordinates are listed clockwise. The second polygon is the trace around the bottom hole. It is shown in green and its coordinates are listed counter-clockwise. The third polygon is the trace around the top hole. It is also shown in green and its coordinates are also listed counter-clockwise.

[image]

There a 7 black pixels. The function should return [[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (3, 0)]]. Notice that the white pixels here do not count as a hole. Also note that the point (1, 2) is permitted to repeat, but no segments of the polygon cross each other. The polygon is shown in red and its coordinates are listed clockwise.

[image]

There are 8 black pixels. The function should return [[(1, 1), (1, 4), (4, 4), (4, 2), (3, 2), (3, 1)]]. The polygon is shown in red and its coordinates are listed clockwise.

I have the following code, but it seems more complicated than may be necessary, and it leaves extraneous points along straight lines. It also doesn't list the bottom left points first. I am hoping there might be a standard algorithm for this task that I just haven't found yet.

```
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL
import shapely


# The array indices place the origin at the top left.
# The graph coordinates place the origin at the bottom left.
# The origin is (0, 0) for both.
# array.shape[0] is the number of rows in the array.
# array.shape[1] is the number of columns in the array.

# Translates the given row and column indices to x and y graph coordinates.
def rc_to_xy(array, r, c):
  r_max = array.shape[0] - 1
  y = r_max - r
  x = c
  return (x, y)

# Translates the given x and y graph coordinates to row and column indices.
def xy_to_rc(array, x, y):
  r_max = array.shape[0] - 1
  r = r_max - y
  c = x
  return (r, c)

# Returns the largest x graph coordinate in the array.
def get_x_max(array):
  return array.shape[1] - 1

# Returns the largest y graph coordinate in the array.
def get_y_max(array):
  return array.shape[0] - 1

# Returns the value in the array at the given x and y graph coordinates.
def get_at_xy(array, x, y):
  r, c = xy_to_rc(array, x, y)
  return array[r][c]


def get_border_line_list(array, x, y):
  center_pixel = get_at_xy(array, x, y)

  x_max = get_x_max(array)
  y_max = get_y_max(array)

  # Locations outside of the array are treated as having a value of 0.

  if x == 0:
    # The center pixel is at the left side of the array. Hence the pixel to the left of it is outside of the array.
    left_pixel = 0
  else:
    left_pixel = get_at_xy(array, x - 1, y)

  if x == x_max:
    # The center pixel is at the right side of the array. Hence the pixel to the right of it is outside of the array.
    right_pixel = 0
  else:
    right_pixel = get_at_xy(array, x + 1, y)

  if y == 0:
    # The center pixel is at the bottom of the array. Hence the pixel at the bottom of it is outside of the array.
    bottom_pixel = 0
  else:
    bottom_pixel = get_at_xy(array, x, y - 1)

  if y == y_max:
    # The center pixel is at the top of the array. Hence the pixel at the top of it is outside of the array.
    top_pixel = 0
  else:
    top_pixel = get_at_xy(array, x, y + 1)


  line_list = []
  # Checks if the center pixel is a border pixel.
  if center_pixel == 1 and (left_pixel == 0 or top_pixel == 0 or right_pixel == 0 or bottom_pixel == 0):
    # The center pixel is a border pixel.

    # These are the directed lines to place at each edge of the center pixel that borders a zero valued pixel.
    left_line = shapely.LineString([[0, 0], [0, 1]])
    top_line = shapely.LineString([[0, 1], [1, 1]])
    right_line = shapely.LineString([[1, 1], [1, 0]])
    bottom_line = shapely.LineString([[1, 0], [0, 0]])

    if left_pixel == 0:
      line_list.append(left_line)
    if top_pixel == 0:
      line_list.append(top_line)
    if right_pixel == 0:
      line_list.append(right_line)
    if bottom_pixel == 0:
      line_list.append(bottom_line)

    # Puts the lines in the line list into a multi line list.
    multi_line_list = shapely.multilinestrings(line_list)

    # Translates the lines in the multi line list to the location of the center pixel.
    multi_line_list = shapely.affinity.translate(multi_line_list, xoff=x, yoff=y)

    # Joins together any lines that share a point.
    merged_line_list = shapely.line_merge(multi_line_list, directed=True)

    # Splits any multi line lists back into line lists.
    merged_line_list = shapely.get_parts(merged_line_list)

    return merged_line_list
  else:
    # The center pixel is not a border pixel.
    return []


def array_to_multi_polygon_list(array):
  border_line_list = []
  for r in range(0, array.shape[0]):
    for c in range(0, array.shape[1]):
      x, y = rc_to_xy(array, r, c)
      border_line_list.extend(get_border_line_list(array, x, y))

  # Joins the border lines returned for all of the pixels into polygons that trace each group of four connected pixels.
  if len(border_line_list) > 0:
    multi_line_list = shapely.multilinestrings(border_line_list)
    merged_line_list = shapely.line_merge(multi_line_list, directed=True)
    merged_line_list = shapely.get_parts(merged_line_list)
    polygon_list = []
    for merged_line in merged_line_list:
      polygon = shapely.Polygon(merged_line)
      polygon = shapely.simplify(polygon, tolerance=0, preserve_topology=True)
      polygon_list.append(polygon)

    return shapely.MultiPolygon(polygon_list)
  else:
    return shapely.MultiPolygon([])


def plot_multi_polygon_list(multi_polygon_list):
  for polygon in shapely.get_parts(multi_polygon_list):
    plt.plot(*polygon.exterior.xy)
  plt.show()


def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('image_file_path', type=str)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  image = PIL.Image.open(args.image_file_path)
  image = image.convert('1')

  array = np.logical_not(np.asarray(image))

  multi_polygon_list = array_to_multi_polygon_list(array)

  plot_multi_polygon_list(multi_polygon_list)


main()
```

Comment: "marching squares"?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That was actually the motivation for the first part of the code that I posted.

Comment: in this case, you'd want to define the "shapes" of the marching squares (2d) or cubes (3d) algorithm to be "cornery". the usual formulations put points between nodes (pixel centers), then use *straight* lines/planes between them, and those usually turn out to be diagonals. -- after this, you'd be left with a ton of tiny line segments. a finishing pass would collapse colinear pieces. since you're on a pixel grid with boolean-valued nodes (pixels), that'll all be integer or half-integer coordinates, so no worries about numerical issues.